# Avoid reloading data each time you want to work on it with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset that never changes (I never modify it directly). I start by reading it with pandas

```
dataset = pandas.read_csv(filepath)
```

and then I do some data analysis. The initial file loading takes about 10 seconds and I am currently re-running it every time I change something in the data analysis part. How can I load the data once and for all and run only the analysis part?

Comment: You could explore environments like iPython, that have a workspace like feature similar to MATLAB.

Comment: There is a function in the standard library that you may find useful: `importlib.reload` reloads a previously imported module.  But the version of the Python is important here: this function was in later versions of the Python 2.x series, was removed for a while in V3.x, and came back in 3.4.  Check the docs for whatever version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this depends a bit on details you haven't shared. Probably the best approach is going to involve serializing the final data structure which you are building.

Create a method which reads in the `csv` and builds whatever data struct you're interested in. Once constructed, output the structure using `pickle`. Then, unpack the datastructure from the pickle when your program loads.

I'm assuming the time-consuming part here is that you are bringing the program up over and over again. If the program is staying up, then you should just be saving the datastructure in a centralized location in active memory. The naive approach here being a global, which you should not do, and I mention just for conceptual purposes.

Comment: I'm just in the exploration phase of the data. I'm running summary statistics, some extractions, plots, etc. I'm doing this step by step as ideas come. I just don't want to reload the whole data every time I try something new. I'd like some Matlab-like behavior : read and save the data for good and then run whatever commands on it.

Comment: If you're just running a python session rather than building a program, then take a look at @John Gordon's answer. If you're building a program around a static datastructure which takes time to build, then deserializing the already built structure will save you a lot of time compared with building it over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

In an interactive Python session, read the dataset:

```
>>> dataset = pandas.read_csv(filepath)
```

Then, wherever you write Python code (in a separate window, or in an IDE, or wherever), create your data analysis function and save it in its own python module.

Import it in the interactive session and run it:

```
>>> from module1 import analysis1
>>> results = analysis1(dataset)
```

Examine the results, decide what changes you need to make, create a new separate python module, and run that:

```
>>> from module2 import analysis2
>>> results = analysis2(dataset)
```

Keep going like this until you're done.