# Keepking numpy.load() safed in memory regardles of rerunning the code

Tags: python, numpy

I'm loading a huge file to process it:
`file = numpy.load('path.txt')`
... everytime I change a single line of code I need to reload the file which takes time. Is there a way to keep the file loaded in memory regardless of re-running the code? and how does loading the file using differernt libraries like panads may differ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid reloading data each time you want to work on it with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807324/avoid-reloading-data-each-time-you-want-to-work-on-it-with-python)

Comment: It does, thank you.

Comment: `np.save` would make a file that is likely faster to load. Converting the .txt to .npy only when you detect that the .txt has changed may speed up work down the line also.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, saving a lot of time :)